# converting a string which contains (html)em-dash to a unified unified form?

Tags: python, python-unicode

An [em-dash](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dash#Common_dashes) can be written in 2 forms,

- the decimal form &#8212;
- the hex form &#x2014;

When they are translated into a html format (displayed in a browser), they shows the same this (—), an em-dash.

Now, when the em-dash gets translated into python again, it gets changed to \u2014.

My question, given a string of either &#8212; or &#x2014;, is there a way to convert them both to \u2014?

Comment: Hmm .... I just saw someone posted an answer that i think it the answer i was looking for. When i clicked on the tick trying to mark it as the answer, somehow it says that the post was already deleted .....

Comment: That was me..I will undelete the answer because I wasn't sure this is what you were looking for

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you need is an html parser

```
#!/bin/python
import HTMLParser
parser=HTMLParser.HTMLParser()
print(parser.unescape("&#8212;"))
```

results

```
—
```

Answer (score 0):

Try [ftfy](https://github.com/LuminosoInsight/python-ftfy). This is a python library for fixing unicode issues.

Answer (score 0):

Someone answered my question, and when I wanted to mark it as the answer, the post seems to have been deleted. Thanks to the original poster.

Here's the answer that he posted:-

```
>>> import HTMLParser
>>> p = HTMLParser.HTMLParser()

>>> p.unescape(u'test8212 &#8212; aaa')
u'test8212 \u2014 aaa'

>>> p.unescape(u'test8212 &#x2014; aaa')
u'test8212 \u2014 aaa'
```